# How to get AdnRecord size via an android application

Tags: java, android, sim-card

the AdnRecord main the file who contain the contacts in the SIM card.

I am developing an android application and I want to get the AdnRecord size via this application by using the AdnRecord class, to be more intelligible , i want to get the AdnRecord size  on a button click .

The AdnRecord class is available as an open source code in internet. I want to make  that my JAVA code  calls this class once we click the button.

the button :

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/third"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/premier"
     android:layout_below="@+id/second"
     android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:text="contact access"
     android:onClick="getAdnRecordsSize" />
```

i want to create a methode "getAdnRecordSize" who calls the AdnRecord class that i saved  in the same package.

Could somebody help me ?! thank you in advance .